# Three JS - How do I change from Lambert to Phong on a material at runtime?

Tags: three.js

I tried setting "type" and then setting "needsUpdate", but it didn't change the type. I know I could make a new material, and then change every mesh that uses that material to use the new material, but I was hoping there was a way I could do it without iterating through every mesh.

Comment: No, you're going to have to create a new material and assign it to all meshes. There are far too many unique elements in play for each material to just changing 'type'.

Comment: I’d recommend you to check the code of the three js editor on GitHub to see what happens when you change  material type

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new material and have the mesh point to it.

`mesh.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });`

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29Lqeadx/.